# 3-way communication via sockets

Tags: perl, sockets

Good Afternoon Gurus,

I am pretty familiar with basic socket programming, and the IO::Socket module but I need to code something now that I have not encountered before. It will be a 3 tier application. The first tier is an event-loop that sends messages upstream when certain events are encountered. The second tier is the 'middle-ware' server, which (among other things) acts as the message repository. The third tier is a cgi application, which will update a graphical display.

I am confused on how to set up the server to accept uni-directional connections from multiple clients one one side, and communicate bi-directionally with the cgi application on the other. I can do either of those tasks separately, just not in the same script (yet). Does my question make sense? I would like to stick with using the IO::Socket module, but it is not a requirement by any means. I am not asking for polished code, just advice on setting up the socket(s) and how to communicate from one client to another via the server.

Also, does it make more sense to have the cgi application query the server for new messages, or have the server push the new message upstream to the cgi application? The graphical updates need to be near real-time.

Thank you in advance,

Daren

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?  Is the problem how to manage communications between several sockets (listening socket, multiple client sockets, and connections to the cgi program) at once?

Comment: John, Yes, you got it. My problem was managing multiple sockets at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said you already have an event loop in the first tier.  In a way, your second-tier server should also arrange some kind of event loop for asynchronous processing.  There are many ways to code it using perl, like [`AnyEvent`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent/), [`POE`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE/), [`Event`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Event/) to name just a few.  In the end, they all use one of `select`, `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue` OS facilities (or their equivalent on Windows).  If you feel comfortable coding in a relatively low-level, you can just use perl's `select` builtin, or, alternatively, its object-oriented counterpart, [`IO::Select`](http://p3rl.org/IO::Select).

Basically you create two listening sockets (you might only need one if the first tier uses the same communication protocol as the third tier to talk to your server), add it to the `IO::Select` object and do a select on it.  Once the connection
is made, you add the accepted sockets to the select object.
The `select` method of `IO::Select` will give you back a list of sockets ready for reading or writing (I am ignoring the possibility of exceptions here).  Of course you have to keep track of your sockets to know which one is which.  Also, the communication logic will be somewhat complicated because you **have** to use non-blocking sockets.

As for the second part of your question, I am a little bit confused what you mean by "cgi" - whether it is a Common Gateway Interface (i.e., server-side web scripts), or whether it is a shorthand for "computer graphics".  In both cases I think that it makes sense for your task to use server push.
In the latter case that's all I'd like to say.  In the former case, I suggest you google for "Comet" (as in "AJAX").  :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed, a gentle push in the right direction. I will give an update when I get it licked.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard CGI application, I don't see how you can "push" data to them. For a client interaction, the data goes through the CGI/presentation layer to the middle tier to remain in session storage (or cache) or to the backend to get stored in the database.

That is of course unless you have a thick application layer which is a caching locus and kind of a middle tier in itself.